# File Structure and what is the difference between mongo, mongo shell, mongod and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, shell

I develop on a Mac.
I am new to MongoDB and have found quite a few very good websites that explain a bunch of things but I am confused about where things Live and how they interface with one another.

MongoDB is a document oriented NoSql database (big data ready) and stores json-like format and allow for sql-like queries against it.
I get this.  I know json format and mysql.

I downloaded the archive folder from the website to my Desktop.
The folder is called:
mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.7

Inside of this folder there is a bin folder which has executable files such as:
mongo, mongod, mongodump, mongostat, mongoexport etc.

To me an executable is a command and means at the prompt $ I can just type the command and run a program.

I use the command line.
I understand that the data/db folder(s) store the data.
I need clarification about the actual scripts that run the MongoDB program - process ?

Sometimes, the Website Tutorial show that we use ./mongo
Why ?

Big questions from me.
I copied the files from my desktop like this:

```
MacBookPro:data regina$ mkdir -p mongodb
mkdir: mongodb: Permission denied
MacBookPro:data regina$ cp -R -n mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.7/ mongodb
cp: mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.7/: No such file or directory
MacBookPro:data regina$ sudo mkdir -p mongodb
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
Password:
MacBookPro:data regina$ ls
db    mongodb
```

Now mongodb lives at the same level as the db.
Questions. 
Will this work?
When I want to launch the mongo shell, from which directory do I use the command  $mongo

I keep getting

```
'-bash: mongo: command not found'.

MacBookPro:/ regina$ cd data
MacBookPro:data regina$ ls
db    mongodb
MacBookPro:data regina$ cd db
MacBookPro:db regina$ ls
journal        local.0        local.ns    mongod.lock    test.0        test.ns
MacBookPro:db regina$ cd ..
MacBookPro:data regina$ ls
db    mongodb
MacBookPro:data regina$ cd mongodb
MacBookPro:mongodb regina$ ls
mongodb
MacBookPro:mongodb regina$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jan 26 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 Jan 26 17:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 root  wheel  238 Jan 26 17:14 mongodb
MacBookPro:mongodb regina$ cd mongodb
MacBookPro:mongodb regina$ ls
GNU-AGPL-3.0        README            THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES    bin
MacBookPro:mongodb regina$ cd bin
MacBookPro:bin regina$ ls
bsondump    mongod        mongoexport    mongoimport        mongoperf            mongos            mongostat
mongo        mongodump    mongofiles    mongooplog    mongoresto    re    mongosniff    mongotop
MacBookPro:bin regina$
```

=======

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read a tutorial about shell/terminal environments so you understand how to run executables, manipulate the working directory, find and set the path, etc. I'll explain the difference between the four mongo*'s in your title.

1. mongo = mongo shell: mongo is an executable that runs the mongo shell. This is an interactive Javascript programming environment used for MongoDB administration and for doing small manipulations of data in the database. For example, I use it extensively to write examples and sample code for SO questions :D
2. mongod: mongod is the executable that is the actual MongoDB database process. After you set it running, you do not interact with it directly. Instead, you send messages to it over the network using a driver, like the one built in to the mongo shell, or the Java driver, or the Python driver, etc.
3. MongoDB: MongoDB is a name for the concept of the database as a whole. It's not a specific executable or part of the software.

Comment: Thanks.  Since I posted I have been through quite a bit documentation and some tutorials.